# Can surjective functions map an element from the domain...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Can surjective functions map an element from the domain to two distinct elements in the codomain? I know that each element in the codomain must have at least one corresponding element in the domain. But for example,

$$f:\mathbb{R} \implies \mathbb{R^*} $$
$$f\left( \frac{a}{b}\right) = a + b   $$

$$s.t.b \neq 0$$

this maps zero to every number, but it still is onto the codomain right?

By the way, $\mathbb{R^*}$ is the set of all real numbers not including zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. No surjective function can do that, because no function can do that. By *definition*, a function is required to map each element of the domain to a **unique** element of the codomain.

I recommend looking at the Wikipedia articles on [functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29), so-called ["multivalued functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function)", and [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: what is it then?

Comment: by the way, your "answer", does not qualify as an answer.

Comment: You can call it a relation. Your $f$ shows why one must be careful when defining a function, because $f$ is not *well-defined*. This means that given an $x$ in the domain, $f(x)$ is not uniquely determined.

Comment: @user28823 If you wanna read about it, functions are a special kind of (binary) [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)). The entity you 'described' (it isn't properly defined) is a binary relation.

Comment: of course, $x_1 = x_2 \implies f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ for all x iff f(x) is a function, thank you